# Android Studio Disable clear automatically logcat

Tags: android, android-studio

when crashed my application and logcat show whats problem Android studio(2.2 Rc2) automatically clear LogCat and i cant see whats error which cause of crash my application,

how can i have that after crash and disable that? i can't find any helpful topic to resolve this problem,

Comment: Restart `Android Studio` once.

Comment: @jaydroider i tested that, unfortunately don't resolve problem, i restarted `pc` too

Comment: Try to find solution here `Run -> Edit configurations... -> Miscellaneous tab -> "Clear log before launch"`

Comment: When your app crashes then you might be seeing a dialogue about saying that it's unexpectedly stopped. Just don't click OK button on that dialog. Log will remain in logcat till then, it will be vanished once you click on OK button.

Comment: @EldarMensutov Thanks, it seems problem resolved, let me to check more

Answer (score 0):

This is not about how to disable automated log deletion, but is about how to see those frustrating deleted errors.
Just click run tab, as shown in image.

[image: Image showing run tab]

I hope this will be helpful